# Where am I going wrong when attempting to evaluate the integral $\int { 3tan^{ 2 }(x)sec(x)dx } $

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate the integral:
$$\int 3\tan^2(x)\sec(x) \,dx $$

We begin by taking the constant outside of the integral to get:
$$3\int \tan^2(x)\sec(x)\,dx $$

Next, we use the identity $\tan^2 (x)=\sec^2 (x)-1$ in order to get:
$$3\int (\sec^2 (x)-1)\sec(x)\,dx$$

We can now distribute the $\sec(x)$ in order to get:
$$3\int (\sec^3 (x)-\sec(x))\,dx$$
which can then be simplified further into:
$$3\int \sec^3 (x)\,dx -3\int \sec(x)\,dx $$

We know that $\int \sec(x)\,dx $ is equal to $\ln (|\sec { (x) } + \tan { (x) } ) +C$, so we can simplify to:

$$3\int \sec^2 { (x) }\,dx - 3\ln (|\sec(x)+\tan(x)) +C$$

Now we must integrate $3\int \sec^3(x)\,dx$. We can do this by integrating by parts:

We start by letting $f(x)=\sec(x)$, $f'(x)=\tan(x)\sec(x)$, $g(x)=\tan(x)$, $g'(x)=\sec^2(x)$

Then we evaluate the integral:
$$3\int { \sec ^{ 3 }{ (x) } dx } =3\sec { (x) } \tan { (x) } -3\int { \sec { (x) } dx } \\ 3\int { \sec ^{ 3 }{ (x) } dx } =3\sec { (x) } \tan { (x) } -3\int { \sec ^{ 3 }{ (x) } -\sec { (x) } dx } \\ 3\int { \sec ^{ 3 }{ (x) } dx } =3\sec { (x) } \tan { (x) } -3[\int { \sec ^{ 3 }{ (x) } dx } -\int { \sec { (x) } dx } ]\\ 3\int { \sec ^{ 3 }{ (x) } dx } =3\sec { (x) } \tan { (x) } -3\int { \sec ^{ 3 }{ (x) } dx } +3\int { \sec { (x) } dx } \\ 6\int { \sec ^{ 3 }{ (x) } dx } =3\sec { (x) } \tan { (x) } +3\int { \sec { (x) } dx } \\ 6\int { \sec ^{ 3 }{ (x) } dx } =3\sec { (x) } \tan { (x) } +3\ln { (|\sec { (x) } +\tan { (x) } |) } +C\\ \int { \sec ^{ 3 }{ (x) } dx } =\frac { 3\sec { (x) } \tan { (x) } +3\ln { (|\sec { (x) } +\tan { (x) } |) }  }{ 6 } +C\\ \int { \sec ^{ 3 }{ (x) } dx } =\frac { \sec { (x) } \tan { (x) } +\ln { (|\sec { (x) } +\tan { (x) } |) }  }{ 2 } +C$$

Finally, we can replace the $3\int { \sec ^{ 3 }{ (x) } dx }$ in $3\int { \sec ^{ 3 }{ (x) } dx } -3\ln { (|\sec { (x) } +\tan { (x) } |) } +C$ to get:

$$\frac { \sec { (x) } \tan { (x) } +\ln { (|\sec { (x) } +\tan { (x) } |) }  }{ 2 } -3\ln { (|\sec { (x) } +\tan { (x) } |) } +C$$

---

So, this appears to be the wrong answer, but even with the aid of wolfram alpha, and other online integral calculators,I cannot seem to pinpoint where I went wrong. I would appreciate help/guidance in this matter.

Comment: Note that there is no reason to enclose every thing that follows \int within {curly braces}.  And ^3 is enough; you don't need ^{ 3 }.  $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I didn't know that something like $sec(x)$ and $\sec { (x) } \\ $ are markedly different. I will edit my post, and I will be sure to use the correct TeX formatting for common functions like $\sin {  }, \cos {  }, \ln {  } $ and etc. from here on out.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Is it better now?

Comment: It looks good now.  When you write $a\sec b$, coded as a\sec b, then proper spacing precedes and follows $\sec$.  Notice that in $a\sec(b)$, coded as a\sec(b), there is less space to the right of $\sec$.  But you your comment you wrote \sec { (x) }, and then you see as much space to the right of $\sec$ as if the parentheses were not there, because the {curly braces} prevent the software from adjusting for the parentheses.  You included large numbers of extra purposeless curly braces.  Those are harmless except for (1) situations like this one, and (2) making editing more onerous, and$\,\ldots$

Comment: $\ldots\,$(3) making inexperienced people who read your code think they braces are needed. In some circumstances braces are needed; for example $a^{+\infty}$ is coded as a^{+\infty}, but in $a^\infty$ it suffices to write a^\infty. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you forgot to multiply $\int\sec^3(x)dx$ by $3$ :

$$\begin{align}&\int 3\tan^2(x)\sec(x) dx\\&=3\int \sec^3(x)dx-3\int \sec (x)dx\\&=\color{red}{3}\cdot \frac {\sec(x)\tan(x)+\ln|\sec(x)+\tan(x)|}{2}-3\ln|\sec(x)+\tan(x)|+C\\&=\frac 32\sec(x)\tan(x)-\frac 32\ln|\sec(x)+\tan(x)|+C\end{align}$$

Comment: Didn't I multiply it already? For example, when I was working on evaluating $3\int { sec^{ 3 }(x)dx } =3sec(x)tan(x)-3\int { sec(x)dx } $, I distributed the $3$.

Comment: @Cherry_Developer: You started with $3\int\sec^3(x)dx$, but what you finally got is $\int\sec^3(x)dx$. So, at the last step, you have to multiply it by $3$. See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d(((3%2F2)*(secx)*(tanx))-((3%2F2)*(log((secx)%2B(tanx)))))%2Fdx%3D3*((tanx)%5E2)*(secx)).

Comment: I apologize, but I do not understand what happened to the $3$ that I distributed as I evaluated the integral $3\int { \sec ^{ 3 }{ (x) } dx }$ by integrating by parts. I made sure to distribute that 3 as I went through all those steps towards the end. I only lost it in the end when I divided both sides by $6$. I guess this is what is really stumping me.

Comment: @Cherry_Developer: OK, let me explain. You distributed $3$ to get $$3\int\sec^3(x)dx=3\sec(x)\tan(x)-3\int\sec(x)dx$$ Then, you correctly got $$6\int\sec^3(x)dx=3\sec(x)\tan(x)+3\ln|\sec(x)+\tan(x)|+C$$ Dividing the both sides by $6$ gives $$\int\sec^3(x)dx=\frac{3\sec(x)\tan(x)+3\ln|\sec(x)+\tan(x)|}{6}+\frac C6$$ Letting $C/6=C'$ to have $$\int\sec^3(x)dx=\frac{\sec(x)\tan(x)+\ln|\sec(x)+\tan(x)|}{2}+C'$$ I hope this helps.

Comment: It's just weird to me how even though I included and distributed the $3$ in my evaluation of $3\int { \sec ^{ 3 }{ (x) } dx } $, that I still had to multiply the end result by $3$ in the end. I thought that since I included it in the evaluation, the $3$ would have already been incorporated in the solution to $3\int { \sec ^{ 3 }{ (x) } dx } $. Nevertheless, multiplying the solution by $3$ as you pointed out does indeed address the error I made.